# How to fix this error "gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie and using Ruby on Rails, I am stucking with this problem. I am trying to make a new project in Ruby on Rails, and when I used this "rails new -X", it gave me this message "an error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.4.4) and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source 'https:rubygems.org/'' succeeds before bundling"

Then I tried the command 'gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source 'https:rubygems.org/'' , it gave me this message : " ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method 'downcase' for nil:NilClass"

I tried to find something from this website "https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap/versions/1.4.4-java" and installed it, but nothing changed.

My gem version is 2.5.2

I know my question is just a little bit stupid but could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: try without mentioning source like this `gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4'`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error `" ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method 'downcase' for nil:NilClass"` because, you mentioned wrong source path.

Replace this

> gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source https:rubygems.org/

with this:

> gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source https://rubygems.org/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I replaced "https:rubygems.org/" with "https://rubygems.org/" , it still have the problem, here is this comment:

"Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/bootsnap-1.4.4/gem_make.out"


And when I go to this file (gem_make.out), I saw it write this :

"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bootsnap-1.4.4\ext\bootsnap/bootsnap.c:484: undefined reference to `mkstemp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bootsnap.so] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2"

Comment: change this to `https:rubygems.org/` this `https://rubygems.org/` there is no forward slashes(//) after `http` in you're mention

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I changed to your comment, it still has an error like this

> ERROR installing bootsnap:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
...
So could you please help me again? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Here is my screen shot, could you please give me some advice or comment? Thank you very much. "http://www.mediafire.com/view/3aar4r663vpxfpi/3.png"